# Pick random item from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database that keeps track of books. The books table looks like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------
   BookID   |    UserID      |     SecID
-----------------------------------------------
     66     |      1         |      3
-----------------------------------------------
     67     |      1         |      2
-----------------------------------------------
     68     |      1         |      5
-----------------------------------------------
     69     |      2         |      2
-----------------------------------------------
```

I want to select a random book that is owned by a specific user from an array of possible sections

For example
if `$userID = 1` and `$arrayA = array(1,2,3);` the output should be either book `66` or `67`

I could have just used `array_rand($arrayA, 1);` and then injected whatever random number the function returns to pull the book with this sql statement

```
SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE userID = '1' AND typeID = '$randomSection' LIMIT 1
```

However, if the `array_rand` function returns 1, the sql statement returns nothing. How can I write a better sql statement that guarantees a result as long as the user has at least one book listed in one of the given sections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  SELECT *
    FROM `books`
   WHERE userID = 1
     AND typeID IN (1, 2, 3)
ORDER BY RAND()
   LIMIT 1
```

The `ORDER BY RAND()` is rather expensive if you have a lot of results matching the condition, but is inconsequential for small result sets and the simplest way to do it.

Comment: Indeed, this is for sure the right answer. Do you happen to know a cheaper way to accomplish the same goal. Theoretically?

Comment: That can depend a lot on your particular data sets. Please search this site, you'll find many answers for this.

Answer (score 3):

Just a bit change in your query:

```
SELECT * FROM 'books' WHERE userID = '1'  order by rand() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Wow! Das ist ja krasse

Comment: rsion
Wählen Sie einen zufälligen Artikel aus der Datenbank
Fragte Vor 8 Jahren, 7 Monaten
Aktiv vor 8 Jahren, 2 Monaten
Gelesen 1k mal

1


1
Ich habe eine Datenbank, die Bücher verfolgt. Der Büchertisch sieht folgendermaßen aus:

-----------------------------------------------
   BookID   |    UserID      |     SecID
-----------------------------------------------
     66     |      1         |      3
-----------------------------------------------
     67     |      1         |      2
-------------

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from t1
where userid = '1' and secid in ('1', '2', '3')
order by rand()
limit 1
```

Of course, the `1` and `(1, 2, 3)` will be parameters there.

Comment: Unfortunately, there only one answer can be accepted. I ranked your answer up though! Thanks